# How often should you get your air conditioner checked and serviced?

Tags: ac, car

Every year I bring my car (now almost 3 years old) to the garage for a check up. When I bring it the people from the garage usually ask if I also want the extra air conditioner check and servicing. Until now I've declined, because the car was rather new and I didn't think it was necessary to spent 130 euros on something that should work anyways. But now the car's warranty period has elapsed.

My question is, is it really necessary to get your air conditioner checked and serviced every year (on a car of 3 years or older)? If not, any recommendations on how often this is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would not bother servicing it unless it is not performing as well any more.

It's hardly a mission-critical feature and I can't see it causing consequential damage with its failure (unlike a timing belt, the oil system or the cooling system).

Answer (score 3):

I've been an auto technician for 28 years. I am factory trained by several manufactures and am ASE certified and I own my own auto repair business. My professional advise is this: Your automotive air conditioning system is a sealed system just like your homes refrigerator.It should only be repaired if it malfunctions.Just I tell my own wonderful customers, "save your money"! If it's blowing nice and cold, there's not much that can be done.I have a 1994 Saturn, It's A/C blows 42 degrees and has never been serviced!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest getting it checked every year, as part of the annual service. Serviced is another matter - whenever it needs to be serviced is the waffley answer, but it really is.

I had a 1997 car that had it's aircon serviced twice in it's lifetime (1997 - 2013), and a 2005 car that is serviced every two years as the pipes aren't great.

Comment: @THelper ... More important than service is actually use. Using your A/C on a regular basis will greatly improve the longevity of the system. The anti-intuitive reason for this is it helps to lubricate the seals in the system, which keeps them doing their job. Without it, they can crack and leak, which causes all kinds of issues as you can probably realize.

Comment: @Paulster2: Exactly - that is what has happened in my 2005 car... that and rust eating a hole into one of the pipes.